# Python Regex - Find contents from a string between two '*'

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file, and I need to extract everything from the file between two '*'s. There can be multiple occurrences of the same. How would I do that using Regex? I am good at Python, but I haven't used Regex a lot so its my weakness.

Comment: I have tried quite a few variants but couldn't make it work. As I said, I'm not good at Regex so couldn't come up with anything substantial.

Comment: It's okay. Josha has answered beautifully well, given the documentation links & the explanation of the pattern too. :)

Comment: Yupe. Thanks a lot for the help, guys! Cheers to SO :)

Answer (score 5):

Notes:

1. Use the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), it's really helpful!
2. `*` is normally a `0 or more` pattern search, so you'll need to escape it with `\`
3. `.` is an `any` search and will capture all characters *except for newlines!*. To include newlines, add the `re.DOTALL` flag
4. `+` means `at least one`, and it is a greedy operator, meaning that it would normally capture *everything* between the first `*` and the last `*` (including any `*`'s in between), so to prevent it from being greedy, we add the `?` operator, which tells it to stop at the first `*` it encounters.
5. `()` Only matches within the parentheses are kept!

And here is an example of that in action:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\*(.+?)\*', flags=re.DOTALL)
text = """Why hello *there my fine
fellow!* How for art thou
on *such a glorious day?*"""

results = pattern.findall(text)
# ['there my fine\nfellow!', 'such a glorious day?']
```

Comment: I am not sure whether the output for `text = '*one***two*'` is really the desired result.