# Extracting text between two strings

Tags: python, text

I am looking to extract the text between two patterns in my text file here is my text:

```
Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final




ONI SACCONAGHI, ANALYST, BERNSTEIN: I have one, and then a follow-up, as well. My sense is that you talked about adjusting for the changes in channel inventory, that you are guiding for relatively normal sequential growth. And I think if you do the math it's probably the same or perhaps a touch worse in terms of iPhone unit growth sequentially, relative to normal seasonality between fiscal Q2 and Q3. I guess the question is, given that you should be entering new markets and you should see pronounced elasticity from the SE device, why wouldn't we be seeing something that was dramatically above normal seasonal, in terms of iPhone revenues and units for this quarter?

Maybe you could push back on me, but I can't help thinking that when Apple introduced the iPad Mini in a similar move, to move down market, there was great growth for one quarter, and the iPad never grew again and margins and ASPs went down. It looks like you are introducing the SE, and at least on a sequential basis, you not calling for any uplift, even adjusting for channel inventory, and ASPs I presume will go down and certainly it's impacting gross margins as you've guided to. Could you respond to, A, why you're not seeing the elasticity, and B, is the analogy with the iPad mini completely misplaced?

TIM COOK: Toni, it's Tim. Let me see if I can address your question. The channel inventory reduction that Luca referred to, the vast, vast majority of that is in iPhone. That would affect the unit compare that you maybe thinking about. The iPhone SE, we are thrilled with the response that we've seen on it.

It is clear that there is a demand there, even much beyond what we thought, and so that is really why we have the constraint that we have. Do I think it will be like the iPad Mini? No, I don't think so. I don't see that.

I think the tablet market in general, one of the challenges with the tablet market is that the replacement cycle is materially different than in the smart phone market. As you probably know, we haven't had an issue in customer satisfaction on the iPad. It is incredibly high, and we haven't had an issue with usage of the iPad. The usage is incredibly high.

But the consumer behavior there is you tend to hold on for very long period of time, before an upgrade. We continue to be very optimistic on the iPad business, and as I have said in my remarks, we believe we are going to have the best compare for iPad revenue this quarter that we have quite some time. We will report back in July on that one, but I think iPhone has a particularly different kind of cycle to it than the tablet market.

TONI SACCONAGHI: Okay, and if I could follow-up, Tim. You alluded to replacement cycles and differences between the iPad and the iPhone. My sense was, when you were going through the iPhone 6 cycle, was that you had commented that the upgrade cycle was not materially different. I think your characterization was that it accelerated a bit in the US, but international had grown to be a bigger part of your business, and replacement cycles there were typically a little bit longer. I'm wondering if it was only a modest difference between the 5s and the 6, how big a difference are we really seeing in terms of replacement cycles across the last three generations, and maybe you could help us, if the replacement cycle was flat this year relative to what you saw last year, how different would your results have been this quarter in the first half?

TIM COOK: There's a lot there. Let me just say I don't recall saying the things that you said I said about the upgrade cycle, so let me get that out of the way. Now let me describe without the specific numbers, the iPhone 6s upgrade cycle that we have measured for the first half of this year, so the first six months of our fiscal year to be precise, is slightly better than the rate that we saw with the iPhone 5s two years ago, but it's lower than the iPhone 6. I don't mean just a hair lower, it's a lot lower.

Without giving you exact numbers, if we would have the same rate on 6s that we did 6, there would -- it will be time for a huge party. It would be a huge difference. The great news from my point of view is, I think we are strategically positioned very well, because we have announced the SE, we are attracting customers that we previously didn't attract. That's really great, and this tough compare eventually isn't the benchmark. The install base is up 80% over the last two years, and so all of those I think bode well, and the switcher comments I made earlier, I wouldn't underestimate that, because that's very important for us in every geography. Thanks for the question.


Q3 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final


I think the tablet market in general, one of the challenges with the tablet market is that the replacement cycle is materially different than in the smart phone market. As you probably know, we haven't had an issue in customer satisfaction on the iPad. It is incredibly high, and we haven't had an issue with usage of the iPad. The usage is incredibly high.

But the consumer behavior there is you tend to hold on for very long period of time, before an upgrade. We continue to be very optimistic on the iPad business, and as I have said in my remarks, we believe we are going to have the best compare for iPad revenue this quarter that we have quite some time. We will report back in July on that one, but I think iPhone has a particularly different kind of cycle to it than the tablet market.

TONI SACCONAGHI: Okay, and if I could follow-up, Tim. You alluded to replacement cycles and differences between the iPad and the iPhone. My sense was, when you were going through the iPhone 6 cycle, was that you had commented that the upgrade cycle was not materially different. I think your characterization was that it accelerated a bit in the US, but international had grown to be a bigger part of your business, and replacement cycles there were typically a little bit longer. I'm wondering if it was only a modest difference between the 5s and the 6, how big a difference are we really seeing in terms of replacement cycles across the last three generations, and maybe you could help us, if the replacement cycle was flat this year relative to what you saw last year, how different would your results have been this quarter in the first half?

TIM COOK: There's a lot there. Let me just say I don't recall saying the things that you said I said about the upgrade cycle, so let me get that out of the way. Now let me describe without the specific numbers, the iPhone 6s upgrade cycle that we have measured for the first half of this year, so the first six months of our fiscal year to be precise, is slightly better than the rate that we saw with the iPhone 5s two years ago, but it's lower than the iPhone 6. I don't mean just a hair lower, it's a lot lower.

Without giving you exact numbers, if we would have the same rate on 6s that we did 6, there would -- it will be time for a huge party. It would be a huge difference. The great news from my point of view is, I think we are strategically positioned very well, because we have announced the SE, we are attracting customers that we previously didn't attract. That's really great, and this tough compare eventually isn't the benchmark. The install base is up 80% over the last two years, and so all of those I think bode well, and the switcher comments I made earlier, I wouldn't underestimate that, because that's very important for us in every geography. Thanks for the question.


Q4 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final
```

I am looking to extract the text between 'Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final' and 'Q3 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final'

and extract text between 'Q3 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final'  and 'Q4 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final' and print or write them to a text file. I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: So show us what you've attempted to write to solve this problem. We're not here to do your job for you - you write some code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings

Comment: `mystring.split(first_boundary_string, 1)[1].split(second_boundary_string, 1)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before asking next time, make sure to look [at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html), go through [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html#regex-howto), take a look at other [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014923/python-regex-find-contents-from-a-string-between-two), and if you still can't find it- make sure to post what you've already tried.

Now, to give you an answer. Assuming you have the full string as the variable `text`

```
import re
target1 = 'Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final'
target2 = 'Q3 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final'
regxp = '{}(.+?){}'.format(target1,target2)
pattern = re.compile(regxp, flags=re.DOTALL)
results = pattern.findall(text)
results
```