# extracting strings between two characters in bytes text file ,Python

Tags: python, string

my data is coming from subprocess and on the output i am receiving :

sample:

`helo, aawe.adam , by the w,: 12.1:\r\n . heesa1.\r\n,b'asdasd',nme.AAAA.\r\n`

`type=<class 'bytes'>`

i want to strip it in one line and then extract only barts between two characters, in this example `.` (dot)

expected result:

```
adam , by the w,: 12
1:
heesa1
,b'asdasd',nme
AAAA
```

I've also tried this method:
[Extracting text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689312/extracting-text-between-two-strings)

but i am receiving errors :
`TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

thanks in advice
`

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try to convert bytes to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the bytes for this to work. Try this:

```
output = b'helo, aawe.adam , by the w,: 12.1:\r\n . heesa1.\r\n,b'asdasd',nme.AAAA.\r\n'
str = output.decode("utf-8")
```

Then you can try to extract the data as you have before.

Comment: yeaa right, thats it! then i can convert output to dataframe and i will receive all required lines, that was so simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> o = b"helo, aawe.adam , by the w,: 12.1:\r\n . heesa1.\r\n,b'asdasd',nme.AAAA.\r\n"
>>> o.split(b".")
[b'helo, aawe', b'adam , by the w,: 12', b'1:\r\n ', b' heesa1', b"\r\n,b'asdasd',nme", b'AAAA', b'\r\n']
```

string split should help you by ignoring first and last item in the splited list.